# XML as complement to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around using XML as complement to HTML. I know what they are used for but I don't quite understand how to use them together.

I know that you can use JavaScript to convert an XML file to HTML, but I don't get how that's going to do the trick. How would I be able to style this HTML-file?

I have a template form, which I want to be accessible on a server and for which I want to enable edits. Once edited I want to save the edits on a separate file, so that the template is still available.(Just so you guys have a little bit of background regarding what I need this for).
After a lot of research I came to the conclusion that I would need to use XML, as I will have to store and transport data.

Could anyone explain in more detail how exactly XML can be used as a complement to HTML? 
If you need more details or information please let me know. I did do a lot of research and I read the other posts regarding how to convert XML to HTML with JavaScript, but that doesn't answer my question about how EXACTLY they complement each other.
I guess my problem here is that I have yet to manage to wrap my head around the concept.

Comment: Typically, a conversion like this would be performed by a [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Comment: So, in the end I would end up with an HTML-file (after converting the XML-file)?

Comment: Yes. A transform can convert arbitrary XML to HTML according to the rules you specify.

Comment: How do I know where that file is located or how can I access it (I'm sorry if that's a stupid question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML` is related to `HTML`, as it uses the same *magic characters* for its markup and the same logic where to put the data.

- The characters `<>` are used to separate the markups from the content.
- The character `&` together with an entity code like `&lt;` is used to encode characters, which would lead to troubles otherwise
- elements can contain attributes like `<someElement someAttribute="attr value">`
- elements can contain text or sub elements

The big difference is, that XML is absolutely free how you name your elements and attributes, while HTML relys on dedicated names (like `<body>`), whereas XML is absolutely strict in structure while HTML allows a lot (like unclosed tags).

As a thing in the middle there is `XHTML`, which is as strict as XML but sticks to the rules of HTML.

It is almost impossible to read HTML as XML, but you can easily create XML which is taken by any browser as a valid web page.

Your issue cries for `XSLT`. This is a method to transform a given XML into a new format. This allows for example, to export your data as XML and create a nice web page from it. Different XSLT will present the same data in different ways.

There are several online tools to test this feature. [you might have a look here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#xslt-examples).

Your statement *After a lot of research I came to the conclusion that I would need to use XML, as I will have to store and transport data* is not all clear...  How you send data (to a web application), and the way you send the (manipulated) data back, is not bound to XML. This is very often done with JSON, using Java Script to read, edit and send it back.

XML -> XSLT - HTML is often seen to create (rather static) reports for a web viewer

Comment: I was told that it'd be best to use a REST API for my purposes and I read that REST API requires an XML file.
Thank you very much for your help!
On another note: is there a way to reference the XML in the HTML file? I have an HTML-file which I have to use but as I said I need XML as well so I can't create a new HTML file from the XML file

Comment: @DisplayName Do I understand this correctly: You ask a REST API and get some XML. You display this information within a web application. Now the user can edit something. Finally the result (XML again) is passed over to the REST API (for storage, whatever)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was planning on doing (if it even works)

Comment: @DisplayName *if it even works* - uhm - what do you think happens, if you type in a comment in this box here on SO? The browser get some content from somewhere, reacts on user input, and sends some data back. This is *business as usual*... But this has nothing to do with *make HTML from XML* ...

Comment: the problem is I did a few small coding projects with JavaScript, Python etc. on my laptop but I've never really dealt with anything like this so I'm sorry if I  seem like an amateur (which I am). Are you saying the way I'm trying to solve this is completely wrong?

Comment: @DisplayName I'm not a web developer, but I'd say yes... Your web application calls a REST API and gets some data. Now use Java Script, Angular or any other appropriate tool to get this data into editable controls. After the user's input (e.g. with click on OK button), use the same tool to create the response data and send it back.

Comment: Since I want the template to be editable, I thought I could simply save the changes/ the input of the user in an xml file. The data that the Rest Api is supposed to get was supposed to be stored in this xml file, isn't that basically the same?

Comment: @DisplayName Well, you might use XSLT to transform an XML to HTML with `<input>` elements, but - to be honest - I would not rely on the structure of an external source... This discussion has gone far off the initial question. Please avoid chameleon questions! My suggestion: Close this question by accepting my answer (if you like it) and start a new question (after you have read about JavaScript, Angular, REST API and web dialogs).